# Rails token field search behaving strange

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

On my local pc my token field works fine. I use a MySQL data.

But on the server where the database i PostgreSQL there is something wrong with the search. I use the this token field plugin: http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/

In my controller I have:

```
def sammenlign
@pakkes = Taletid.where("navn like ?", "%#{params[:q]}%")
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @pakkes }
      format.json { render :json => @pakkes.map(&:attributes) }
    end
end
```

Why is the like method not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For postgres try ILIKE instead of LIKE. Postgres is case-sensitive by default.

Comment: I will try it as soon as possible :)